# Why is isset($this->var) always returning false in my Codeigniter model?

Tags: codeigniter, isset

I'm using Codeigniter 3 with PHP 7.

In one of my models, I'm trying to set a user id variable if a user is logged in and save it to a db. In all of my controllers, there is a session check at the top and if the user is logged in, it sets $this->uid. The code I am using in the model is shown below. $uid always saves as NULL.

```
if(isset($this->uid)){
    $uid = $this->uid;
}else{
    $uid = NULL;
}
```

If I try without the boolean (as shown below), the $uid var returns the user id value and saves properly to the db if the user is logged in and an error if the user is not logged in. So I'm confident the error is not a missing value in $this->uid.

```
$uid = $this->uid;
```

Comment: can you post the var_dump($this->uid); ?

Comment: Result from var_dump($this->uid) while logged in: string(1) "1"

Answer (score 2):

Codeigniter 3 uses `__get()` magic function in `CI_Model` to achieve controllers properties in the model. (You can verify on: [CI 3 github](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/Model.php#L59))

Check the `var_dump($this);` code in your controller, and model. In the controller you will see the property name and its value, but in your model you won't.
Check the `var_dump($this->uid, isset($this->uid));` as well. You will see the value in both controller and model, but the `isset()` will fail in your model.

**You can fix it, if you create an `__isset()` magic function in your model class.**
For example (models/User_model.php):

```
class User_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        // Without declaring __isset() magic func, the isset($this->uid) returns with bool(false)
        var_dump($this, $this->uid, isset($this->uid)); // object(User)#14 (0) { } int(69) bool(true)
    }

    public function __isset(string $property): bool
    {
        return isset(get_instance()->$property);
    }
}
```

In you controller (controllers/User.php), you just assign a value to `$this->uid`.

```
class User extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->uid = 69;
        $this->load->model('user_model');
    }
}
```

*Note:* More professional way, if you create a `MY_Model` class which extends from `CI_Model`. In this class you can define the `__isset()` in the way above. The only difference is that, the `User` class (and other models) will extends from the new `MY_Model` and you create it in the `application/core` folder.

Here you can learn more about [Property overloading](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get) in PHP.
Sorry, for late answer, hope I could help for someone!

Comment: Appreciate the answer. Unfortunately I don't have any way to check if it fixes the problem anymore. Hopefully it helps someone else :)